# jQuery show hide some elements

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

I have a problem. I hope you can help me.

I have a list with images of people. On mouseover a div with more information is shown. In a list the names are highlighted.

Now my problem. On click the image, the div with more information should be displayed and not disappear.

The same with the names in the list. On mouseover the more information div shoud be shown. On click, the div should appear.

The mouseover effects work. But I can not realize the click effect.

```
[Here is a shortened example][1]
```

I think you can do this in sleep...

Thanks Kai

Comment: please share your html and script

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8HEGr/2/ Here the Link.

Comment: _"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."_

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can really answer your question, but this may help

Instead of this:

```
$('div'+'.nn_'+team_id).css("display", "block");
```

Do this:

```
$('div'+'.nn_'+team_id).show()
```

Jquery also has the .hide() method for hiding elements. .toggle() can also be used to hide/show.